# goQueryによるWebスクレイピング

Tags: go, web-scraping

```
doc, err := goquery.NewDocument("https://translate.google.co.jp/?hl=ja#en/ja/apple")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Print("url scarapping failed")
}
fmt.Println(doc.Find("span #result_box").Text())
}
```

jqueryでgoogleの翻訳結果を取ってきたいのですが、翻訳結果が表示される

```html
<span id="result_box">(ここに表示される)</span>
```

のところが空白になってしまっています。
pythonで実装した時はできているのですが、goではできません。なぜでしょうか。

Comment: こちら、PhantomJS の様なヘッドレスブラウザが必要なのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

試しに https://translate.google.co.jp/?hl=ja#en/ja/apple を開いてみたところ、こんなDOM構造でした。

```
<span id="result_box" class="short_text" lang="ja"><span class="">林檎</span></span>
```

サンプルコードから空白文字を取ると取得できるかなと思います。

```
doc.Find("span#result_box").Text()
```